# With emberjs, how to extend the attributeBindings parameters from a parent view?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, attributes, ember.js

I try to have some inheritance with  attributeBindings between two View.

```
(function(exports) {
Ember.MobileBaseView = Ember.View.extend({
    attributeBindings:['data-role', 'data-theme'],
    'data-theme': 'a'
});
})({});


(function(exports) {
Ember.ToolbarBaseView = Ember.MobileBaseView.extend({
    attributeBindings:this.get('attributeBindings').concat(['data-position']),
    'data-position': function() {
```

I have try *this.get('attributeBindings').concat(['data-position'])* and *Ember.MobileBaseView.get('attributeBindings').concat(['data-position'])* and *Ember.MobileBaseView.attributeBindings.concat(['data-position'])*

Perhaps, I should just do *attributeBindings:['data-role', 'data-theme', 'data-position'],* but I would rather find a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ember.View#attributeBindings` is a [concatenated property](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L59), which means if you overwrite it in a subclass, the values from the superclass are concatenated. So this works, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/r72dz/:

```
Ember.MobileBaseView = Ember.View.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['data-role', 'data-theme'],
    'data-theme': 'a'
});


Ember.ToolbarBaseView = Ember.MobileBaseView.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['data-position']
});​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinkings that's not working this way because of an error in my code. I learn a new thing today :).